# Align div and image to background cover on rezoom of browser window

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a landing page and have 4 sections of the website: **home**, **about**, **download**, **contact**. Section home and download have background images which stretch correctly for the background of the page. I use the following css for that:

```
.download {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/image.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

The download section has the following content:

```
  <section id="download" class="download content-section text-center">
        <div class="download-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <h2>Header</h2>
                    <div>Text</div>
                </div>
                <img src="img/myimage.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

This looks all nicely on my big 21 inch screen however when I resize the window, the elements from the download section are stretching beyond the background image and into the contact section.

How can I make sure, that all elements are being aligned correctly, i.e.:
- No elements from one section are displayed above the elements of the next section
- The myimage.png is being resized if needed not to be displayed into the next section
- If the section does not fit on one page, the background image stretches down until the end of the current section.

Comment: Try `min-height: 100%;` instead of `height: 100%;`.

Comment: Where exactly? I tried playing around with this, but can't find a solid css config for this.

Comment: `.download {
  min-height: 100%;
  ...
}`

Comment: did you try adding a style for the myimage.png of max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;

Comment: yes, tried both of the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After trying various things and with the help of the comments, here the working CSS:

```
.download {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/image.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}

.download img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```